My implemented TextEncryptor works on /encrypt /decrypt but not in propertySource read
in spring cloud config server i implemented a custom TextEncryptor to encrypt and decrypt properties with my own encryption algorithm (i need to be like this) and i made a bean of TextEncryptorLocator to expose my own TextEncryptor as a base for encryption and decryption.
it successfully works when encrypt/decrypt with spring config server endpoints :
curl localhost:8888/encrypt -s -d mypassword
682bc583f4641835fa2db009355293665d2647dade3375c0ee201de2a49f7bda

curl localhost:8888/decrypt -s -d 682bc583f4641835fa2db009355293665d2647dade3375c0ee201de2a49f7bda 
mypassword

but when i store a property like

org.prop={cipher}682bc583f4641835fa2db009355293665d2647dade3375c0ee201de2a49f7bda

it doesn't use my custom TextEncryptor for decryption and it simple return this :
{
  "name": "cclient",
  "profiles": [
    "dev"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": null,
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
     {
       "name": "classpath:/config-repo/cclient/application-dev.properties",
       "source": {
          "org.prop": "682bc583f4641835fa2db009355293665d2647dade3375c0ee201de2a49f7bda"
        }
      }
   ]
}

what i did is :
 public class MyTextEncryptor implements TextEncryptor {
    private final static String secret = "A_SECRET_FOR_ENCRYPTION_AND_DECRYPTION" ;
 
    @Override
    public String encrypt(String text) {
        // my encryption algorithm based on my secret
        return "encrypted text";
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String encryptedText) {
        // my encryption algorithm based on my secret
        return "decrypted text";
    }
 }


@Bean
@Primary
public TextEncryptorLocator textEncryptorLocator() {
    return new TextEncryptorLocator() {
        @Override
        public TextEncryptor locate(Map<String, String> keys) {
            return new MyTextEncryptor();
        }
    };
}

@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class CServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(CServerApplication.class, args);
    }

 }

and my bootstrap.properties :
spring.application.name=cclient
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.name=application
spring.cloud.config.label=latest


Alright after spending hours on this and checking spring-cloud-config source in Github I finally found the answer and it is :
we should redefine CipherEnvironmentEncryptor bean with new TextEncryptorLocator which use MyTextEncryptor and make it Primarry
so i added these lines and it works
@Bean
@Primary
public CipherEnvironmentEncryptor cipherEnvironmentEncryptor(TextEncryptorLocator textEncryptorLocator) 
{
    return new CipherEnvironmentEncryptor(textEncryptorLocator);
}

